# Magento 2: What is the purpose of breadcrumbs in the backend?

Tags: magento2, admin, backend, breadcrumbs

I'm curious if anyone has some insight. In the Magento 2 admin, as with Magento 1.x, breadcrumbs are not displayed on admin pages despite methods being available to add them via blocks/controllers.

In Magento 2 backend controllers extends `Magento\Backend\App\Action` which includes the method `_addBreadcrumb`. I have seen use of the method in many tutorials as if using it when developing a custom module should be a foregone conclusion. However, I cannot find a single admin panel that renders out breadcrumbs in any manner.

So what's the point of this? Are breadcrumbs used in the admin in some hidden manner I am not aware of? Is it, like I suspect, a common feature they just add to controller relevant classes yet will not be used in the admin unless a developer modifies admin templates? Am I going to get downvoted because I'm asking a dumb question?

I just find it strange that something so commonly referenced is not used by its own developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does **NOTHING**. You can see in `\Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Breadcrumbs`.
[image]